# Adding a Notes using WEB API

Tags: acumatica

I have gone through the WEB Api for leads and not able to find a proper field to update Notes for Leads.

I have used SOAP for creating sales order where NoteText is exposed to update the notes and what is the relevant field in WEB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `note` property. 
The value for this property must be specified directly (without nested object with `value` property).
Below is an example of the body of the PUT request:

```
{
    "LeadID": {
        "value": 11973
    },
    "note": "Some very interesting note\nSome other text from new line."
}
```